# Lead Window Function Returning Unwanted Rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

thanks for checking this out.

I am working on a lead-window function in Redshift and am receiving additional unwanted rows. In this query users have 4 test scores, I wish to have each row contain a distinct user and display their 4 scores in the columns I have created.

I am getting the desired row, but am also receiving 3 additional rows, each with an increasing number of NULLS.

```
user_id,
lead(score, 0) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by user_id order by id asc) as first_score,
lead(score, 1) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by user_id order by id asc) as second_score,
lead(score, 2) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by user_id order by id asc) as third_score,
lead(score, 3) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by user_id order by id asc) as fourth_score
from test_scores

enter code here
```

Comment: that is because you have four rows in your table, you will get four rows in your result set

Comment: to convert your rows to columns you need something like a PIVOT

Comment: Lead is just the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Window function does not cause rows to become grouped into a single output row. Can you share sample data?

Comment: To be clearer, the FROM clause (including any joins) defines a result set.  The WHERE clause extracts rows from the result set, and the SELECT clause extracts columns from the result set.  The LEAD function is merely a way to refer to values in one row from another row.  It doesn't do anything else